# pip-compile failed due to python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: pip, python-3.7

When I run

```
pip-compile
```

The following error shows up in my Mac Terminal

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/pip-compile: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have been trying for hours but couldn't find a solution. I am on Mac and my homebrew is updated. pip-tools are updated too.

I later switch to Conda and used Python 3.10 and I get the same error message. Oddly in Conda, the Python3 should be python 3.10 but it still says python3.7 in the error message. Could someone help?  Thank you!